# Can I disable Javascript with a Safari Extension?

Tags: javascript, safari

I would like to build a Safari extension that would add a button to the Toolbar showing if JavaScript is Enabled or Disabled and acting as a toggle on click.

Is it possible to enable or disable JavaScript from a Safari Extension?

I added a keyboard shortcut to the Develop menu, but the button would show the status without having to check the menu.

Comment: Do you require more information to accept the answer below? I think you want to know if you can change the status of the button, but please let me know what you need clarified.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source project for a Safari Extension that disables Javascript:

http://jsblocker.toggleable.com/

You could probably extend that to meet your needs.